# Method in python to obtain the following pattern string

Tags: python, regex, google-bigquery

I am getting the List of tables from BigQuery using  [`tylertreat/BigQuery-Python`](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) and the following code is here,

```
class get_Tables:
    def GET(self,r):
          web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',      '*')
          web.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
          tables = []
          datasetID = web.input().dataSetID
          client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account,
                            private_key_file=key, readonly=True)
          result  = client._get_all_tables(datasetID,cache=False)
          tablesWithDetails =    result["tables"]
          for inditable in tablesWithDetails:
              tables.append(inditable["id"])
          print(json.dumps(tables))
          return json.dumps(tables)
```

The above method returns an JSON like this,

> ["thematic-scope-112013:Demo.Airport_Traffic",
>   "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.Alcohol_Consumption",
>   "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.Flight_paths",
>   "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.GDP_Country_Wise",
>   "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.like_data",
>   "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.medicare_cost"]

but i just want without the project and dataset name,

what is the pattern or regex to obtain in the following format,

> ["Airport_Traffic", "Alcohol_Consumption", "Flight_paths",
>   "GDP_Country_Wise", "like_data", "medicare_cost"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for regex just a split method would be enough. ie, split every list item according to dot and then get the last element from that splitted list.

```
[i.split('.')[-1] for i in data]
```

*Example:*

```
>>> data =  ["thematic-scope-112013:Demo.Airport_Traffic", "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.Alcohol_Consumption", "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.Flight_paths", "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.GDP_Country_Wise", "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.like_data", "thematic-scope-112013:Demo.medicare_cost"]
>>> [i.split('.')[-1] for i in data]
['Airport_Traffic', 'Alcohol_Consumption', 'Flight_paths', 'GDP_Country_Wise', 'like_data', 'medicare_cost']
```

Comment: or `.rsplit(".",1)[1]`

Comment: [i.split('.')[-1] for i in tables]
          {
              newtables.append(i)
          } , this does not return correct data, sorry am new with python

Comment: How you get the input data? It's not a json, it's a list. JUts assign the result back to tables like `tables = [i.split('.')[-1] for i in tables]`